# Copying Dropbox links in bulk

Tags: dropbox

I have uploaded my folder, which contains over 400 images, to Dropbox and now I need to copy all these images’ Dropbox links in Excel. Copying the links one by one & pasting them in Excel is a lengthy procedure as there are 400 images.

Is there any option in Dropbox which will display multiple files sharing links and let me copy all at once?

Answer (score -1):

No it is not possible to share  url for images all at once within a folder

When you click on the image to share it will fetch the location of a file and will frame the url to download and sharing is up to user's option.

This process is handled in program code as **single threaded** and not as multi-threaded. So it is not possible to share url of more files at once unless dropbox releases new feature for it

Hope this helps!